# Active Today link missing for question edit bump

Tags: support, edits, bump

See this question.

[Algorithm for hours occupied in day by tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062359/algorithm-for-hours-occupied-in-day-by-tasks)

It was asked yesterday, edited just now, which caused it to be bumped to the top of the list.
[image]

Usually when something is bumped there is an "Active: Today" link that I can click on to see what the latest change causing the bump was, but it doesn't appear for this question.

[image]

Is this by-design or is it a bug?

If it's by design, what other events bump but don't cause the "Active: Today" to show?

---

See below for an example of there an edit to the question with the Active Today linked to it (hovering over the link confirms it):

[image]

Comment: It looks fine now.

Comment: That's because someone posted an answer, which also bumped it. The today link is linking to that (as it now should).

Comment: Hmm correct. I just edited [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16074952/1369235) today (which was posted yesterday) it came in active tab too. But it is not showing `active today`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/gIuqD.png